# gvim: delay after hit-enter-prompt

Tags: vim

Sometimes after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the hit-enter-prompt appears, gvim hangs several seconds before redrawing the screen. Precisely, 1 second after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the cursor appears on the screen (i.e. inside the buffer window), after 3 additional seconds the screen is redrawn.

This happens if I jump to a tag (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>), but not if I execute a command like `:!ls`. Both actions show up the hit-enter-prompt, but only the former one leads to the delay.

What is the reason for this delay?

Edit:
I noticed that the problem appears only when jumping to a tag and the line "tag 1 of 2 or more" does *not* appear. Instead a message like

> src/module.cxx 483L, 15688C
>   src/module.cxx 483L, 15688C
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

is shown, where I don't know what the numbers mean (these are not the line numbers of the tags or of the line from where I jump). The filename is one of the files in which the tags are found. The other tag-containing file (src/module.h) does not appear.

Unfortunaltely, I don't know how to provoke this situation.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but is `lazyredraw` set? Assuming no scripts are executing, that shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: `lazyredraw` is not set here.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to a setting or script you have installed. You can debug your scripts by disabling some plugins to figure out what's happening.

## Use default vim settings

```
gvim -u NONE -U NONE
```

**Issue still occurs:** likely happens in a default vim install. May be a bug.

**Issue is fixed:** it's an installed config setting or plugin. Try disabling plugins.

## Disable all plugins

```
gvim --noplugin
```

**Issue still occurs:** config setting (vimrc or gvimrc). Try commenting out parts of your rc files to see if it still happens.

**Issue is fixed:** it's an installed plugin. Try disabling plugins until it's fixed.

## Other notes

Some Linux distributions may include custom settings for vim (such as debian.vim) that may make your results different from others.

You might also get slightly different results if you **remove** your vimfiles. I'm not sure. You can easily stash up all of your vimfiles:

```
mkdir ~/bak
mv .*vim* ~/bak
```

Comment: I have `set insertmode` in my .gvimrc. If I start gvim (with only a filename as parameter), then deactivate `insertmode`, then jump to a tag, the hit-enter-prompt is not shown, although there are 2 tags. When `insertmode` is active, the hit-enter-prompt is shown on the same action (same source file, same tags file, same tag). The same is true for `showmode`: when activated, the hit-enter-prompt disappears, when deactivated, the hit-enter-prompt appears.

Comment: Does that behaviour still occur with `gvim -u NONE -U NONE --cmd "set nocp insertmode" Somefile.java` (vim defaults except turn on insertmode)? If I do that and have some java source files with the same method name reused and type `<C-o><C-]>` to jump to a tag, vim jumps and says "tag 1 of 2 or more". I see no delay.

Comment: Also, I don't think showing all matching tags is the default behaviour. See `:help tag`. Do you have a map to `:tselect` or have `:set cscopetag`?

Comment: One thing to check that might be the cause of your delay is a map for hitting Enter. Type `:map <CR>` after you see the delay. If `<CR>` is mapped in a chord, then vim will wait for `timeoutlen`. (So `:map <CR>a` will cause vim to wait to see if you're going to type `a`.) [See also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158516/#2158610) that mentions delays related to esckeys (which you're using for the arrow keys in insertmode).

Comment: With `gvim -u NONE -U NONE --cmd "set nocp insertmode"` I see no hit-enter-prompt, i.e. no "tag 1 of 2 or more" message. I also see no delay in this case, as the delay only appears when the hit-enter-prompt is shown.

Comment: `cscopetag` is NOT set here. Also, I have no map to `:tselect` (as far as I can tell, using the `:map` and `:imap` commands).

Comment: No, I have no mapping to <CR>. Also, setting `timeoutlen` to a small (10 ms) or big (10000 ms = 10 s) value does not change anything, so I guess there is no mapping problem.

Comment: Found new fact: if I get a "tag 1 of 2 or more" message, hitting Enter does NOT lead to a delay. But in certain circumstances I get a message like "src/module.cxx 483L, 15688C<CR>src/module.cxx 483L, 15688C" (don't know how to insert a newline in this comment). I don't know what the numbers mean (these are not the line numbers where the tag is located, nor the line numbers from where I jumped), but the filename names the file to where I jump. Also, the line "tag 1 of 2 or more" is NOT shown in the message. The delay seems to only appear in this case, but I don't know at all how to provoke it.

Comment: That would be good to add to the question. I assume none of your source files have 15k columns, so maybe there's something wonky about your tags file. How big is it? Are you using a recent version of exuberant ctags? Can you replicate your problem if you only build tags for a few files?

Comment: My tags file is 115k in size. I use Ctags 5.8, and used the switch -n. If I build the tags only for a few files (tag file = 22k), I get the same problem. Omitting -n doesn't help. I assume that there is no problem with ctags.

Comment: I just realized that my tselect/cscope comment isn't what you're seeing. You never see a list of tags so of course you aren't using those. What text is causing the Press Enter prompt? Is it always only the double print of `src/module.cxx`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. When I position the cursor over a class name and hit <CTRL-]> I see that dubious 2 lines (note that in fact, there are 2 tags - the class and its constructor). Do you have an idea what that output means or why it is printed at all? I don't understand it. Perhaps when I knew what it means I could make further investigations...

Comment: I just realized that `483L, 15688C` means that your file src/module.cxx is 483 *lines* and contains 15688 *characters*. Are those values correct?

Comment: You could try grabbing the [latest vim code](http://www.vim.org/mercurial.php) and see if it was a bug that's been fixed. If that doesn't help, [the vim_use mailinglist](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use) might have some better ideas for troubleshooting. See also `:help bugs` for reporting issues.

Comment: Yeah, you're right: 483 lines and 15688 characters. And I'll try the latest version at home next days (I'm @work here and should not invest too much time ^^). Thanks for your help so far. If I found a solution, I will post it here.