# Vim determine what mappings are assigned to a key

Tags: vim

My 'O' command (enter a new line above this one and enter insert mode) is slow to take effect. It seems like this is because there is some other mapping, such as 'OP' , and that vim is waiting when I hit 'O' to see if I want 'O' or 'OP'. I don't know what set this mapping, it's not anything in my .vimrc. I'd like to find it and change it so I can go back to having snappy 'O' commands, but I don't know how to find it.

Is there a way to see a list of what mappings a key is involved with? Note: I do not want to reduce my timeout setting.

Thanks

Comment: Try `:verbose map O`.

Comment: This fixed the issue for one problem I was having, but not for the 'O'. It returns: `No Mappings Found`

Comment: That command only gives you information, it doesn't fix anything. "No mapping found" means that there's no mapping using O so... where did you get that OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:verbose map O
```

tells you which mappings start with `O`. That usually gives you the right hint about mappings that execute only after a short delay. For the `O` mapping in particular, you may also suffer from the problem described in [delay before o opens a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158516/delay-before-o-opens-a-new-line).