# Strange behaviour of "O" command in vim

Tags: vim

When I press O, the vim editor prints the character "O", and only after 1 second it erases the character and runs the command (opens a blank line above the current line, and switches to insert mode).

The "o" command works fine.

Why is this?

PS: below is my .vimrc :

```
colorscheme default
set nocompatible ai sw=4 smarttab smartcase ignorecase showcmd noshowmatch
set guifont=Monospace\ Bold\ 11
map <BS> X
sy on

" Encoding selection - read file
set wildmenu
set wcm=<TAB>
menu Encoding.koi8-r :e ++enc=koi8-r<CR>
menu Encoding.windows-1251 :e ++enc=cp1251<CR>
menu Encoding.ibm-866 :e ++enc=cp866<CR>
menu Encoding.utf-8 :e ++enc=utf-8<CR>
map <F8> :emenu Encoding.<TAB>

" Encoding selection - save file
set wildmenu
set wcm=<Tab>
menu Encoding.Write.koi8-r :set fenc=koi8-r<CR>
menu Encoding.Write.windows-1251 :set fenc=cp1251<CR>
menu Encoding.Write.cp866 :set fenc=cp866<CR>
menu Encoding.Write.utf-8 :set fenc=utf8<CR>
map <S-F8> :emenu Encoding.Write.<TAB>
```

Comment: what happens if you set the [timeoutlen](http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v57/options.html#'timeoutlen') and [ttimeoutlen](http://www.polarhome.com/vim/manual/v57/options.html#'ttimeoutlen') to some small value, e.g. 50?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2158610/553523

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect due to the way vim handles arrow keys. Arrow keys are sent to vim as escapes sequences followed by `O` followed by `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.

If you type any of the following by hand you will see that vim will move the cursor in the corresponding direction.

- `<esc>OA` moves `<up>`
- `<esc>OB` moves `<down>`
- `<esc>OC` moves `<right>`
- `<esc>OD` moves `<left>`

If you just continue typing the effect should be negligible.

---

If you are in compatible mode (one way to get it `vim -u NONE`) you would just see  `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` on a new line every time you hit one of the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking

```
:verbose map o
```

and

```
:verbose nmap o
```

This should give you all relevant mappings that start with an "o".

**Edit** You should check for `map` or `nmap` since you're in *normal mode* when this awkward behaviour occurs. Checking for `imap` won't help because that only shows the mappings that are applied while in insert mode (which you are not).

Comment: "No mapping found" (both for map and nmap).